# Curve25519 choice of the prime

Tags: elliptic-curves

In the paper for [curve25519](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) is described how the prime was chosen. But I don't understand why the biggest 255-Bit prime was chosen instead of a 256 Bit prime. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: https://moderncrypto.org/mail-archive/curves/2014/000237.html

Comment: Do I get this right: $2^{255} - 19$ is faster than $2^{256} - 189$ and this is more important than a non significant boost in security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty good answer to the question can be found [here](https://moderncrypto.org/mail-archive/curves/2014/000237.html)

I try to give a shorter and more precise answer: The Curve25519-standard uses a pretty specific modulo-algorithm. A pseudocode of the algorithm looks like this:

```
def fastModulo(num, prime):
    # Basecase:
    if num < prime: return num
    if num < 2*prime: return num-prime
    # Split number in upper and lower bits:
    upper = upperBits(num)
    lower = lowerBits(num)
    # calculation:
    factor = differenceToPowerOfTwo(prime)
    nextnum = factor * upper + lower
    # recursion:
    return fastModulo(nextnum, prime)
```

The algorithm is faster if factor is smaller. So the difference to a power of two is important for the speed of the standard. Therefore the biggest 255 Bit prime was chosen instead of the biggest 256 Bit prime, because a significant speed boost is more important than a non signficiant security boost.